# Automatically generate and export into PDF Crystal Reports 10

Tags: pdf, crystal-reports

I have a created a report using Crystal Reports 10. The report contains information about the activity of a person. I need to generate and export this report into PDF for a number of persons (e.g. 70) automatically and save each PDF file with the name of the person, so I will get 70 PDF files.

I have searched for a solution on the Internet but did not manage to find anything helpful.
Can anyone help me with an answer?

Thank you!

Comment: You need to provide what you've tried so far and where you're stuck. Show us your code that you wrote until now to face this problem and then surely somebody wants to help you!

Comment: are you looking for a tool or for code ?

Comment: Until now I have only created a report with a parameter and I can generate a PDF with the information for all persons. So, the report is 2 pages long/ person, so I now have a PDF with 140 pages. I have downloaded a soft that splits this PDF into parts and I split and renamed each individual file manually. I am interested in knowing if anyone knows a solution for this that does not involve manual labor. If there is an option in Crystal Reports or I can do this with some code or tool, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should hook up a parameter to the report's record filter - this way, you can make the report display only records for one particular person.

Then it's just a matter of writing a loop that sets the parameter value and exports a (uniquely named) PDF for each person.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. This is my first time using Crystal Reports, so I am not very sure where I can program this loop. Could you please give more details?

Comment: There's two key parts here - the parameter on the record filter and setting the parameter programmatically. You already (based on your question) have the code to export to PDF. The loop I mention is just a `for` loop to iterate over all the possible parameter values (your 70 users), and set the parameter value into the report before calling your existing export code.

Comment: I have indeed a report with a parameter, but I do not have any code for exporting the report into PDF. Now I do all this by hand, 70 times. I select the value for the parameter, refresh the report and then click on Export button in Crystal Reports to export into PDF.

Comment: Well, you can use the CR SDK in a few different languages (ie: Java, VB) - you need to pick one and get familiar with the basics before trying to go any further: get your code to open the report and export it like you're doing manually now.  Once you have that, try using the parameter API as I've described. If you get stuck, update your question with your code - it tends to be a lot easier to get useful help here when you have a code sample.